# Woocommerce print simple product attributes on cart and checkout, like variable attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show attibutes from a simple product, in cart and checkout. Just like variable products does, but there is only one attibute. See image below:

[image: Simple product attribute walkthrough]

Is this possible to achive with PHP?

I was thinking about something like using echo $product->get_attributes()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the follows code snippets to achieve your above task -

```
function modify_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if( $item_data || $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ) return $item_data;
    if ( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
    $attributes = array_filter( $cart_item['data']->get_attributes(), 'wc_attributes_array_filter_visible' );

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        $values = array();

            if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
                $attribute_taxonomy = $attribute->get_taxonomy_object();
                $attribute_values   = wc_get_product_terms( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $attribute->get_name(), array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                foreach ( $attribute_values as $attribute_value ) {
                    $value_name = esc_html( $attribute_value->name );

                    if ( $attribute_taxonomy->attribute_public ) {
                        $values[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $attribute_value->term_id, $attribute->get_name() ) ) . '" rel="tag">' . $value_name . '</a>';
                    } else {
                        $values[] = $value_name;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $values = $attribute->get_options();

                foreach ( $values as &$value ) {
                    $value = make_clickable( esc_html( $value ) );
                }
            }

            $item_data[] = array(
                'key'   => wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() ),
                'value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values ),
            );
        }
    }
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'modify_woocommerce_get_item_data', 99, 2 );
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks! I'm using a plugin to generate pdf invoices, is it possible to make the code work in the pdf invoice too? 

Here are some hooks and examples that works with the pdf
invoice: http://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/pdf-template-action-hooks/

Comment: Yes it's possible. All you have to do is use this `wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta` hook for PDF invoice and as per this hook available parameters you have to fetch product object using `$item`. After then just replaced `$cart_item['data']` with your current product object. That's it.

Comment: Hmm.. Im not so good at PHP just yet. So i can't seem to make it work. I Changed the hook. But i don't know what to do with $item and $cart_item['data]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Please try adding a filter as bellow,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', function($name, $cart_item) {
    //has attributes
    if ($cart_item['data']->is_type( 'simple' ) && $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes()) {
        $name .= " - ";
        foreach ($attributes as $att)
            $name .= $att->get_name() . " : " . implode(',', $att->get_options());
    }
    return $name;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for your answer! But the code does not seem to work. It says the website are experiencing technical problems.

Comment: I've updated code to remove the error for variable products. Review my example (http://lankabird.com/testsite2/shop/) in here.